# Black Screen when Shutting Down

Tags: shutdown, screen, bios

The past 2 shut downs have ended with a black screen with my computer not turning off. I was forced into a hard reset by holding the power button down for 7 seconds. How do I stop this from happening?

I am also afraid of restarting my computer, for the same issue. I usually just shut down, count to 10 and boot up.

My motherboard is GA-990FXA-UD3 with version F5 BIOS. Could the BIOS be the issue? I've read online it might be unstable with Linux (in this case, Ubuntu 16.04) Could this have also caused the black screen I got on boot up before I changed the GPU drivers?

Comment: Never mind, I just shut down again and it worked perfectly fine. Maybe it was just a glitch?

Comment: Immediately after rebooting go to terminal and type 'journalctl' press end key and the page up until you see time of shut down lock up. Copy error messages into you question.

Comment: Has anything changed like maybe a USB Device was plugged in before?

Comment: I had my camera memory card plugged into a USB slot. I pulled it out before shutting down this time. Could that have been the problem? That's very odd.

Comment: Easy enough to test if the SD Card was causing lock up. Insert, Shutdown, Repeat.

Comment: Okay, so I tested it.  It shut down successfully  with the device plugged in. But it flashed text on a black screen upon both shut down and boot up. Text that does not read "Loading Operating System". So I'm assuming that means it IS the memory card, but that Ubuntu is learning to ignore it? I'm going to stop worrying about this now.

Comment: You can delete this question and post a new one if it happens again. In the mean time type `journalctl` in the terminal. Hit the `End` key and tap `PageUp` key to review recent system events, including error messages.

Comment: will the errors be highlighted in a different color, or be marked with the word, "error"?

Comment: Unfortunately not always. Bluetooth error messages show in big bright red. However you can grep for certain phrases to appear. I'm a little `grep challenged` but there are lots of great people on here who know it well.